# How to connect to a mysql server with multihost?

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, How to connect to a mysql server with multihost ?

In this picture, it's just an exemple my host in my server is "Database_Server_2" not "Database Server 2" and i have a port "81"

[image]

I try this code, but i don't work :/

```
 $link = mysql_connect('localhost:81/Database_Server_2', 'db_user', '******');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not connect multiple host in one connection, you have to use resource identifier($link) to manage connection like:

```
$link1 = mysql_connect('localhost:81/Database_Server_2', 'db_user', '******');
$link2 = mysql_connect('localhost:81/Database_Server_2', 'db_user', '******');
```

also mysql_connect will be deprecate very soon, use mysqli or PDO, they also better in performance.

Comment: no, 
Work :
     $link1 = mysql_connect('localhost:81', 'db_user', '******');
Don't work : 
     $link1 = mysql_connect('localhost:81/Database_Server_2', 'db_user', '******');

Comment: login in phpmyadmin, copy host from there and then put it in host area.

Comment: also, i don't think your mysql server is running on 81 port. check it on console/terminal if possible.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support such named instances. The name "Database Server 2" is most probably only a name given to it in the phpMyAdmin config file, so you don't have to bother with remembering which IP/Port is which.

Look in the config file of phpMyAdmin, the second instance will be using a different port than the first instance. Just providing the port should work.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost:81', 'db_user', '******');
```

And the usual note: `mysql_` functions are deprecated and will be removed from PHP in future versions. You should not write new code using them, use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.